# Extract ggplot2 color code information generated from `scale_fill_gradient`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't think this question has ever actually been *answered* on Stack Overflow ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174185/extract-color-information-from-ggplot2) provides a workaround, but that is all I could find, and the question is now over 10 years old).

I want to extract the color code information generated from the `scale_fill_gradient(low = "skyblue", high = "dodgerblue4")` code used in the `ggplot2` code shown below.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt*1000, mpg)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, aes(colour = hp)) +
  xlab("Weight (pounds)") + ylab("Miles per gallon (MPG)") + labs(color='Horse power') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1000, 6000), 
                     breaks = c(seq(1000,6000,1000)), 
                     labels = c("1,000", "2,000", "3,000", "4,000", "5,000", "6,000")) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "skyblue", high = "dodgerblue4") +
  theme_classic()
```

Ideally, I would like to generate a dataset with a row for each point in the plot and columns with all the standard information (`wt`, `mpg`, `hp`) but then also the color code of the individual points that can be seen on the plot. This would correspond with the `hp` ("Horse power") variable, as seen below, and would (presumably) be generated by the `scale_fill_gradient` function. This would allow me to reproduce the color of a point on the plot with an `hp` score of, say, 150.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract any data, including colour codes, that the geom layer uses from the plot using `layer_data()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt*1000, mpg)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, aes(colour = hp)) +
  xlab("Weight (pounds)") + ylab("Miles per gallon (MPG)") + labs(color='Horse power') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1000, 6000), 
                     breaks = c(seq(1000,6000,1000)), 
                     labels = c("1,000", "2,000", "3,000", "4,000", "5,000", "6,000")) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "skyblue", high = "dodgerblue4") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```r
ld <- layer_data(last_plot())
(head(ld))
#>    colour    x    y PANEL group shape size fill alpha stroke
#> 1 #204464 2620 21.0     1    -1    19    4   NA    NA    0.5
#> 2 #204464 2875 21.0     1    -1    19    4   NA    NA    0.5
#> 3 #1C3C5A 2320 22.8     1    -1    19    4   NA    NA    0.5
#> 4 #204464 3215 21.4     1    -1    19    4   NA    NA    0.5
#> 5 #2E618C 3440 18.7     1    -1    19    4   NA    NA    0.5
#> 6 #1E4261 3460 18.1     1    -1    19    4   NA    NA    0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for! Also, if anyone wants to visualise the `colour` variable in this answer, you can do it with the code found in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918696/display-of-specific-colors